# Cast String to date time in Stream analytics Query

Tags: azure, stream, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

We are sending datetime as string in the format 2018-03-20 10:50:037.996, and we have written Steam analytics query as below.

```
SELECT
    powerscout.Device_Id AS PowerScout,
    powerscout.[kW System],
    CAST(powerscout.[TimeStamp] AS datetime) AS [TimeStamp]
INTO
    [PowergridView]
FROM
    [IoTHubIn]
```

When we are sending data through Stream analytics, Job is getting failed. 
Any Suggestions please.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

ASA can parse DATETIME fields represented in one of the formats described in ISO 8601. This format is not supported. You can try using custom JavaScript function to parse it.